# iptables port forwarding troubleshooting

Tags: centos, iptables, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward connections on port 18600 to port 9980. I have this in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Mon Oct 21 18:30:43 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:280]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12:768]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [12:768]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 18600 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9980
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Oct 21 18:30:43 2013
```

and `/etc/init.d/iptables status` shows me this:

```
Table: nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:18600 redir ports 9980
```

However, I can telnet from localhost to port 9980, but not 18600. What am I missing? (This is a CentOS-based VM.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packets from the local machine do not pass through the NAT PREROUTING table.

Test from another machine.

If you need to DNAT the traffic that originates from the local machine, use the NAT OUTPUT table.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea a different table was involved for local traffic. NAT OUTPUT was exactly what I needed.